# C# Smtp mail doesnt work 5.5.1 Authentication error

Tags: c#, smtp

I know this may sound like a duplicate but I HAVE TRIED EVERYTHING my code is below

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("XXXXXXXXX@gmail.com", "XXXXXXXX@gmail.comm");

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",587);
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("XXXXXXX@gmail.com", "yyyyyyyYYYYY");
client.EnableSsl = true;

mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
mail.Body = "this is my test email body";

System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
};

client.Send(mail);
```

The error happens on this line of code:

```
client.Send(mail);
```

Error code is 5.5.1. I also tried turning allow less secure apps ON

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, [read more](https://www.smarterasp.net/support/kb/a1546/send-email-from-gmail-with-smtp-authentication-but-got-5_5_1-authentication-required-error.aspx)

the error might occur due to the following cases:

case 1: when the password is wrong

case 2: when you try to log in from some App

case 3: when you try to log in from the domain other than your time zone/domain/computer (This is the case in most of scenarios when sending mail from code)

Answer (score 0):

In [this thread](https://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/23569/solved-551-authentication-required-with-smtpgmailcom.aspx) someone found out this can happen if your Gmail password is too weak. He changed his password -> his code worked. He changed it back: Google wouldn't allow the password.

> Then, for an experiment, I tried changing my password back to my
>   previous password to see what would happen, and Gmail didn't actually
>   allow me to do this, citing the reason "sorry we cannot allow you to
>   save this change as your chosen password is too weak" and wouldn't let
>   me go back to my old password.

So: Try changing you Google password.

Answer (score -1):

Could it be a sender that is wrong, @ gmail.comm?

Comment: This seems rather a comment than an answer.